# Grails Acegi: update username

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I'm using the Acegi (AKA Spring Security) plugin in my Grails app. In`SecurityConfig.groovy` I have added the line

```
userName = 'email'
```

such that the email field is used as the username. I find that if I change the email field and save the object, e.g.

```
user.email = 'my_new_email@foo.com'
user.save(failOnError: true)
```

The save completes without error, but the email field is not actually updated. My guess is that the Acegi plugin prohibits changing the username field, but I'd be grateful if someone could confirm.

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 3):

The domain object used by acegi is cached. As a matter of enormous coincidence I had the same problem this week and [wrote up the solution](http://manbuildswebsite.com/2010/03/10/updating-the-logged-in-user-with-acegispring-security-in-grails/) yesterday!

In summary you have two options:

Turn off caching of the domain object by adding cacheUsers = false to your SecurityConfig.groovy

Refresh the domain object by replacing it in the SecurityContextHolder

```
private def refreshUserPrincipal(user) {
    GrantedAuthority[] auths = user.authorities.collect {
        new GrantedAuthorityImpl(it.authority)
    }
    def grailsUser = new GrailsUserImpl(
        user.username
            "",
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            auths,
            user);
    def authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(grailsUser, "", auths)
    SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication = authToken
}
```

(Check the source of [GrailsUserImpl](http://plugins.grails.org/grails-acegi/trunk/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/springsecurity/GrailsUserImpl.java) to see what all those true values mean!)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do :

```
String oldUsername = user.username
user.username='my@newusername.com'
user.save()
if(oldUsername != user.username) {
  SpringSecurityUtils.reauthenticate(user.username, null)
}
```